# Which websites give step by step explanation to how a picture is taken?

Tags: digital, web, picture-samples, internet

I randomly came across this article

http://www.dpreview.com/articles/7670130459/editorial-lighting-the-minimalist-way -

I would like to find out if there are any websites there are dedicated to explaining how pictures are been taken, ie the steps by step / camera settings & equipment used.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Searching for [photography "behind the scenes"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=photography%20%22behind%20the%20scenes%22&meta=) takes you to a variety of sites where pro and amateur photographers explain how a shot was done.

DP Challenge also has a ["How'd They Do That"](http://www.dpchallenge.com/how.php) section.

Comment: You can also post it as a question here and we'll do our best to work out how a shot was made.